# Removing segments from String

Tags: java

Im parsing HTML code from a site and I'm nearly done.  I have the section of text i need from the site, but occasionally there are some links included in the HTMl that i wish to get rid of.  I am thinking of using the fact that all of the elements I do not want start with '<' and of course and with '>'.  Is there anyway to do this?  This is what I have so far.

```
for(int i = 0; i<desc.length();i++)
    {
        if(desc.charAt(i)==('<')){

        }
    }
```

desc being the string i want to trim up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally considered a bad idea to parse markup languages like XML and HTML manually. However, if you are only trying to remove all the elements, I could see where a simple script may be useful.

Something I thought worth mentioning, is that if you remove all elements of the HTML, you may have several pieces of text jammed together. Check out this piece of code, see if it helps.

```
public class RemoveHtmlElements {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>My First Heading</h1>"
                + "<p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>";

        boolean elementsExist = true;
        while(elementsExist) {
            if(html.contains("<")) {
                int open = html.indexOf("<");
                int closed = html.indexOf(">", open);
                html = html.substring(0, open) + " " + html.substring(closed + 1);
            } else {
                elementsExist = false;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(html);

    }

}
```

This should clean HTML of any bracketed elements. It will input a space where it removes an element to keep text from being jammed together unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this;

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
boolean open = false;
for (char c : desc.toCharArray()) { // iterate over the characters
  if (c == '<') { // if we hit a less then store that the tag is open.
    open = true;
  } else if (open && c == '>') { // if the tag is open and the close symbol hits close.
    open = false;
  } else if (!open) { // if the tag isn't open
    sb.append(c);
  }
}
System.out.println(sb.toString()); // print the string.
```